# How to preserve white spaces in function arguments in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to create a version of InStr function for Informix 11.5. Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_INSTR(txt VARCHAR(255), term VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNING VARCHAR(255);
  DEFINE i INTEGER;
  DEFINE len INTEGER;
  DEFINE lenterm INTEGER;

  LET i = 1;
  LET lenterm = LENGTH(term);
  LET len = LENGTH(txt) - lenterm;

  WHILE ( i <= len ) LOOP
    IF SUBSTR( txt, i, lenterm ) = term THEN
      RETURN i;
    END IF
    LET i = i + 1;
  END LOOP

  RETURN 0;
END FUNCTION;
```

I'll use this function to get the first name of a user in a column with the full name, like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, MY_INSTR(name, " ")) AS firstname
  FROM users
```

I need to pass the value `" "` as the term, but when I do, `lenterm` equals 0.

Is there a way to preserve white spaces when passing them to a function in Informix?

Comment: In the SQL language string literals are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @mustaccio: In Informix, it is permissible, and even customary, to use double quotes.  You have to work hard (set an environment variable) to make double quotes behave as markers for delimited identifiers.  This is basically due to ancient history (early- to mid-80s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `VARCHAR` types, the `OCTET_LENGTH` function should return the length including trailing spaces.
From the [manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1519.htm):

> The OCTET_LENGTH returns the number of bytes in a character column,
>   including any trailing spaces.

I didn't have an informix 11.50 instance to test, but tried the following in an Informix 12.10 (FC6DE):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_my_t(param1 VARCHAR(10))
RETURNING INTEGER AS param1_length;
  DEFINE l_result INTEGER;
  LET l_result = OCTET_LENGTH(param1);
  RETURN l_result;
END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION f_my_t (' ');
```

The result I got:

```
Database selected.
Routine created.

param1_length
            1
1 row(s) retrieved.

Database closed.
```